# Displaying Images from an API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace a background image using jQuery.

The image is being called from an API, below is a fiddle with the JSON data.

https://jsfiddle.net/m15xg45j/

This JS Fiddle contains the full code all HTML, CSS and JS

https://jsfiddle.net/bsu6m5es/2/

My JS

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key' : "***",
    'q' : "health"
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result){

    var articles = result.response.docs;

    for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++){
        $("h2").each(function(index, el){
            $(el).html(articles[index].headline.main);
        });

        $(".article--snippet").each(function(index, el){
            $(el).html(articles[index].snippet);
        });

        $(".post").each(function(index, el){
            $("el").css("background", "url(" + articles[index].thumbnail +")");
        });

        // console.log(articles[i].url);

        $(".linked--headline").each(function(index, el){
            $(el).attr("href", articles[index].web_url);    
        });

        // console.log(articles[i].web_url);
    }
}).fail(function(err){
    throw err;
});
```

Comment: You should try not to post sensitive information like api-keys when posting your code; it was still present in the JSFiddle

Comment: @maxwell it's cleared out.

Comment: oops meant to post this on the example in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the 'done' method, run the success method:

Based on what the data structure you have presented, you need to run a for loop and use filter over the multimedia property. Check the code

https://jsfiddle.net/bsu6m5es/3/

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

url += '?' + $.param({
'api-key' : "67dac4e994164fca920f7a8420e28dc2",
'q' : "health"

});

$.ajax({
url: url,
method: 'GET',
success : function(result){

var articles = result.response.docs;

for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++){
    $("h2").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).html(articles[index].headline.main);
    });

    $(".article--snippet").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).html(articles[index].snippet);
    });

    $(".post").each(function(index, el){
        $("el").css("background", "url(" + articles[index].thumbnail +")");
    });

    // console.log(articles[i].url);

    $(".linked--headline").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).attr("href", articles[index].web_url);    
    });

    /// Your thumbnails:
    for (var i=0;i<r.response.docs.length;i++)
    {
          var thumbUrl = r.response.docs[i].multimedia.filter(function(el){ return el.subtype='thumbnail'})[0].url;
    // e.g: thumbUrl = 'images/2017/02/28/science/28BRODY/28BRODY-thumbWide.jpg'

    }
    // console.log(articles[i].web_url);
}
}).fail(function(err){
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: Hey @AHBaheri thanks for your answer, however that solution breaks the app and does not explain how I can get the thumbnail to show from the JSON data.

Comment: You posted your api key just FYI

Comment: @scrippyfingers I have updated the answer. Remove your api from the public post and vote up if you find this answer helpful.